# Show previous results after reload

Tags: support

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion) I reload my tags page which displays questions related to my tags. If I want to go back to the previous results/page reload, with a question I wanted to check I can't do it because it's going back to a different page (or blank). Sometimes questions are deleted or changed tags so it's hard to find them.

Can I go to the previous view? Is it impossible?

**EDIT** I asked a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395235/view-last-results-on-stack-overflow-after-reload-page) question in Stack Overflow site (not meta) but no answer yet.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. A reload clears the browser's cache.

Comment: Can this question be ask in stackoverflow site (not meta)?

Comment: If you cared about the technical details or ask how to write your own tag page that supports this feature, yes it might be on topic on the main site. But this question really looks like a support request, it's suited well on meta.

Comment: I've given a general answer to the non-meta version of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812916/8684601 To summarize: the user can't do anything on their own, it is up to SO to improve the UX. This meta question is the perfect place to discuss concrete improvements to SO that will help UX.